# ms-access: syntax error missing operator in query expression:

Tags: sql, ms-access, macros

here is my query:

```
SELECT IIf([Lab Occurrence Form].[2 0 Analytical (Testing Phase)] Like ‘*2.5*Other*’,’2.5 Other’,[Lab Occurrence Form].[2 0 Analytical (Testing Phase)]) AS [Occurrence Code], Count([Lab Occurrence Form].[2 0 Analytical (Testing Phase)]) AS [Count]
FROM [Lab Occurrence Form]
WHERE ((([Lab Occurrence Form].[Occurrence Date]) Between Forms!Meeting_Reasons_Frequency!Text4 And Forms!Meeting_Reasons_Frequency!Text2)) And [Lab Occurrence Form].[2 0 Analytical (Testing Phase)] Like '*2.*'
GROUP BY IIf([Lab Occurrence Form].[2 0 Analytical (Testing Phase)] Like ‘*2.5*Other*’,’2.5 Other’,[Lab Occurrence Form].[2 0 Analytical (Testing Phase)])
HAVING ((Count([Lab Occurrence Form].[2 0 Analytical (Testing Phase)]))<>0);
```

i am getting an error:

```
syntax error missing operator in query expression: GROUP BY IIf([Lab Occurrence Form].[2 0 Analytical (Testing Phase)] Like ‘*2.5*Other*’,’2.5 Other’,[Lab Occurrence Form].[2 0 Analytical (Testing Phase)])
```

does anyone know what is the problem here?

here is an example where my query worked and it was basically the same thing: THIS WORKS:

```
SELECT IIf([Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)] Like '*1.11*Other*','1.11 Other',[Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)]) AS [Occurrence Code], Count([Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)]) AS [Count]
FROM [Lab Occurrence Form]
WHERE ((([Lab Occurrence Form].[Occurrence Date]) Between Forms!Meeting_Reasons_Frequency!Text4 And Forms!Meeting_Reasons_Frequency!Text2)) And [Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)] Like '*1.*'
GROUP BY IIf([Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)] Like '*1.11*Other*','1.11 Other',[Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)])
HAVING ((Count([Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)]))<>0)
ORDER BY IIf([Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)] Like '*1.11*Other*','1.11 Other',[Lab Occurrence Form].[1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the correct single quote type

`‘ and ’ != '`

Comment: ALSO pls anyone lese who reads this HAVING should come after WHERE at least in my case